# How to add comments in particular text in the Docs file using python

Tags: python, python-docx

i want to add comments in particular text in my microsoft document using python **Bayoo-docx** and **python-docx** can anyone please help me. I am using Bayoo-docx.

I want some help with the bayoo-docx and python-docx code.